# beacon minor variable global

Tags: ios, swift, beacon

i need ur help! i do an app and i need said that the "minorBeacon" do a global variable, because in other ViewController i will called. but i can't and the other problem is convert this data to "Int"

```
    func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didRangeBeacons beacons: [CLBeacon], inRegion region: CLBeaconRegion) {

    if let beacon = beacons.first {
    var minorBeacon : Int = beacon.minor
       print(minorBeacon)


        }
```

the problem says 
 "cannot convert value type "NSNumber" to specified type "Int" " help me please!!

Thanks Guys ! :)

Comment: What are you even saying?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can user [`intValue`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/nsnumber/1412554-integervalue) to get the [`NSNumber`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/nsnumber)'s value as a Swift `Int`:

```
func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didRangeBeacons beacons: [CLBeacon], inRegion region: CLBeaconRegion) {

if let beacon = beacons.first {
    var minorBeacon = beacon.minor.intValue
    print(minorBeacon)
}
```

Comment: thanks! and how i can call this var "minorBeacon" in other view controller ??  i try with this :                                                                                                  var myCustomViewController: ViewController = ViewController(nibName: nil, bundle: nil)
        var linkInternet = myCustomViewController.minorBeacon

Comment: Pick up a good resource on iOS design. You can't just instantiate ViewControllers like that.

Comment: To be precise: `intValue` returns an `Int32`, and `integerValue` returns an `Int`.

Comment: Oh yes, I was referencing Swift 3 documentation